# A HREF Doesnt work on 3rd level, Using parallax CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have small problem with Parallax CSS, for some reason in my third div, it does not want to make the tags `<a>` Clickable, I believe the problem is within  "z-index:-1;" by changing it to positive, im pretty sure it will fix this issue but i need z-index: -1 to be able to run parallax css.

Here is the coding for my 3rd Div, which is having the a href non clickable issue.
`#about-us` second div, works fine with `<a>` tags, `#portfolio` does not work `<a>` tags.

```
#about-us:before {
    background-image: url("images/bg_4.jpg");
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index:-1;
}
#portfolio {
    background-image: url("images/bg_3.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the z-index to be negative? Negative z-index items can't be clicked.

Comment: Increase the z-index of your other items so that you can fit your pseudo element onto a layer that has a positive z-index.

Comment: You already answered your own question. It's the negative z-index that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the kind answers! all of you rock, I can't set the z-index to positive because that will break my scrolling script.

is there any other method besides setting to positive? 

i am running a scrolling type of page (parallax scrolling), which uses a lot of negative z index, for this case setting z index its not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element with a negative `z-index` will never be clickable, this is by design. You should make the `z-index` of all your other elements higher so you don't have to give this div a negative one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy, do you know any other way to override this?